# How to add a dynamic class as type parameter in a generic class

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I am developing an application with C# and angular, I want to make a generic service on the server-side which can be used by any controller
[It is the service class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRCVL.png)

until now everything seems to be OK, but when I want to inject it as shown below
[I inject the service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRHBu.png)

this shows this error
[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfQVH.png)

please guide me on how to solve this problem

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. If you're going to us `ControllerService<dynamic>` then why bother making it generic in the first place?

Comment: Also, please don't post images of code, always add your code to the post.

Comment: But the error you are seeing is because the framework doesn't know what to do with the string parameter of the `ControllerService` constructor.

Comment: so how can I make such a generic service and how to inject it

Comment: the answer to the first comment is that, If I don't make it generic how the class knows on which object this should update the database

Comment: But you need to inject a specific version of it into each of your services right?

Comment: yes, but I want to prevent DRY, many functionalities are the same I want to make a generic service that can be passed to any controller to do CRUD operation, is there any way to do so?

Comment: Look, you still haven't posted your code here despite being asked to do that instead of posting images of code. So I'm afraid I am going to let someone else help instead.